# Android Studio : Error in 'getDefaultdProguarFile()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am unable to build project.
I don't know how this error came, till yesterday it was working fine.

Here is my error log.

Error:(17, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'getDefaultdProguarFile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'MyAppName' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

And this is my build.gradle (app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ashishkudale.MyAppName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultdProguarFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: you have a typo. It is **getDefaultProguardFile** not `getDefaultdProguarFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `getDefaultdProguarFile` it is `getDefaultProguardFile`.
It is typo error. Corect it, the build be done.